# How much should I isolate my method for unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking

I have the following method:

```
public < V extends U > boolean matchesObject (V object, String filter) {

    if (filterIsAny(filter)) return true;

    else {

        List<T> targets = getFilterTarget(object);

        for (T t : targets) if (matches(t, filter)) return true;
        return false;

    }

}
```

where filterIsAny(filter) is a trivial method (just checks filter != null).

My question is: when I'm unit testing, is it worth to mock this method so that I'm sure that my function follows the correct path in the function, or do I just assume that my filterIsAny(filter) works and test using the real method? In this particular case, it is pretty easy to mock this method, but I have other instances where it would take several lines of code to mock intermediate results returned by trivial functions, such as list.indexOf(object) in a list of mocked objects.

I know it wouldn't be "pure" unit testing, since theoretically I'd be testing more than one function at a time, but how is is worth doing pure unit testing when it takes more work than finding the error in the code in the case of the test failing?

Comment: Why do you need an extra method for testing != null?

Comment: Well, it does a bit more than testing that filter != null, but it's all pretty trivial. In any case, it's just an example, my intention with this question is to find out to which extent I should try to isolate my code when testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assume that `filterIsAny` works until it gains non-trivial logic.**

If your function is a wrapper for a single pure Java statement which has no logical branches, you can safely skip writing a unit test for it, and therefore only it in other unit tests. What you *do* want to test are the various branches in the method to be tested, assuming it has non-trivial logic.

Here, you would setup your filter object such that it produces a `true` and a `false` result when testing `matchesObject(V object, String filter)` based on the logical branch you're testing (no match in collection, one match in collection, invalid collection type (if possible), null input, etc.)

In your case, you can skip the `filterIsAny(filter)` evaluating to true branch, since you execute a trivial statement `return true` afterwards.

By the way, consider refactoring to `Stream.anyMatch()` if possible; it will reduce the number of return statements in your function and enhance readability.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do that